# ReSharper C# Naming Convention for DTOs

Tags: c#, resharper

I try to customize the naming rule for classes that when I see or create a DTO that the name is actually `FooDTO` and not `FooDto`.
But I couldn't solve the problem that ReSharper checks every class and marks every class that has not a Dto in its name.

Can I create conditional rules that are only triggered on actual DTOs?

Comment: Yeah I I'm in the the `Dto` camp. Though I must admit i used to hate it, I have bigger things to worry about now though ;)

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot setup ReSharper to do this. I would solve it with a meta unit test that use reflection to check that the expected classes follow your naming conventions.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Would be a nice feature to have conditional namings in the ReSharper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do in your case would be simply the following:

> Add another rule with the DTO suffix

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now R# is happy again as if nothing happened.

Alternatively, you can turn these warnings off in different ways:

> Add the abbreviation to team-shared settings

[image]

> Use `SuppressMessage`

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming")]
class WhateverDTO
{
    
}
```

Comment: I personally cant get past the white VS theme.... :)

Comment: Yeah tried exactly the same. But after this every class was marked. Not the outcome I wanted :/

Comment: @00110001 that's because I'm a ‍♂️

Comment: @RobinKaltenbach check out my edit, first option just works fine here